# Chrome on Mac: Mouse Button 4 Not Longer Opens Links in New Tab

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mouse

I have a Macbook Air and a Microsoft Mouse 4000.  When using Chrome and holding the mouse in my right hand, the button on the left side of the mouse, which is under my right thumb, and which I believe is referred to as Button 4, used to open links in a new tab.  Suddenly now it goes "Back."

The use of Button 4 to open new tabs is so engrained in my everyday work that it's driving me nuts.  I tried downloading the Microsoft Intellipoint mouse driver and preference pane, but making changes there has had no effect on this issue in Chrome.

Firefox used to behave the same way, and still does.  That is, Button 4 still opens a link in a new tab when using Firefox.

Does anyone have any idea how to troubleshoot this or get the original behaviour back?

Comment: I have the same problem with Chrome on macOS. I can't find a solution, the only way to open a url in a new tab is to CMD + click it. Really annoying, as this changes my workflow. I guess I'll start using Firefox.

Comment: I found this same issue in Chrome on another Mac, so it is not machine-specific.  I installed and ended up removing some add-ons that allow for gestures and such, but none simply allowed me to assign the mouse buttons to particular actions.  Getting used to clicking the mouse wheel, which is so clunky.  Off-topic, I have also switched to Brave.  The same button layout exists on Brave as well, but hey at least I have some of my privacy back.